# AS3 Video COMPELETE event handler not working? addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE

Tags: actionscript-3

hi i am using FLVPlayback 2.5 component and getting this error, please help! - cannot convert fl.video: to flash.events.VideoEvent.

as3 code using -

```
            comp.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, videoComplete);

            function videoComplete(event:VideoEvent):void {
                trace("videoComplete");
            }
```

full error -

> TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert
>   fl.video::VideoEvent@6e974dd1 to flash.events.VideoEvent.     at
>   flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()     at
>   flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()     at
>   fl.video::FLVPlayback/http://www.adobe.com/2007/flash/flvplayback/internal::handleVideoEvent()
>     at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()    at
>   flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()     at
>   fl.video::VideoPlayer/http://www.adobe.com/2007/flash/flvplayback/internal::httpDoStopAtEnd()
>     at
>   fl.video::VideoPlayer/http://www.adobe.com/2007/flash/flvplayback/internal::httpNetStatus()

fix thanks to ronnie! cheers man. this works for me..

```
            import fl.video.VideoEvent;

            comp.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, videoComplete);

            function videoComplete(event:Event):void {
                trace("videoComplete");
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lostPixels was right for the most part in explaining what the error means but it isn't `VideoEvent`, its simply `Event`

```
 comp.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, videoComplete);

 function videoComplete(event:Event):void //event:Event not event:VideoEvent
 {
     trace("videoComplete");
 }
```

Comment: Yep. Please mark this answer correct if it is what you have used as your solution. thanks!

Comment: @Ronnie although what you told hime will work, it works for the wrong reasons... see my answer above so that you guys can all see what is REALLY going wrong.  Best!

Comment: this seems to be working for me! - function videoComplete(event:Event):void{ - thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

I made a comment up there but I wanted to give you a full explaination here.  When you said:

```
addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, videoComplete);
```

it does in fact call your function... but with a different event than you expect.  This is because it is actually firing a fl.video.VideoEvent which ALSO has a constant called COMPLETE.  Both Event.COMPLETE and VideoEvent.COMPLETE = a string value "complete" so it calls you function.

Second problem is the function:

```
function videoComplete(event:VideoEvent):void {
```

is listening for a flash.events.VideoEvent.  This was probably an accident when you used the code complete.  But when you function get called, it is receiving a fl.video.VideoEvent... thus the error

so do these:

```
import fl.video.VideoEvent;

addEventListener(VideoEvent.COMPLETE, videoComplete);

function videoComplete(event:VideoEvent):void {
```

And you are all set!

Comment: hi thanks but if i just import - import fl.video.VideoEvent; and use comp.addEventListener(VideoEvent.COMPLETE, videoComplete); function videoComplete(event:VideoEvent):void { i get this error (i am using flash ide with a document class) - 1119: Access of possibly undefined property COMPLETE through a reference with static type Class.

Comment: you must still have flash.events.VideoEvent in your import statements. fl.video.VideoEvent.COMPLETE is 100% for sure what you want.

Comment: fl.video::VideoEvent@6e974dd1 to flash.events.VideoEvent in your error shows that videoComplete(event:VideoEvent) was expecting a flash.events.VideoEvent.  and your new comment that is says COMPLETE doesn't exist means it's looking in the wrong class flash.events.VideoEvent.

Comment: to prove the theory, change this:  function videoComplete(event:fl.video.VideoEvent):void {

Comment: and this: addEventListener(fl.video.VideoEvent.COMPLETE, videoComplete);

Comment: well, you've got something else going on then. FLVPlaybock definitely dispatches a fl.video.VideoEvent.  Sorry you couldn't get it working with the proper Event... but using event:Event will work... as long as you never need to know anything about the event... only that it happened.

Comment: thanks, i am not sure might be a bug with cs6 or something for your help very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think this might have something to do with the flash player version you are targeting.
Can you target FP9 or FP10? (in the properties panel in Flash Professional)

Comment: thanks i read the same thing but tried the 11.1 but same issue, will try lowering it.

Comment: i lowered it to 10.3 did nothing same issue. i cant export to 9 as thats to old.

Answer (score 1):

Type Coercion fails are the result of you trying to convert one strictly typed variable to another. What that means (it's not written to be easily understandable) is this:

Say we have two variables, one is a number, and one is a string. If we try and say number = string, Flash will spit out that error, because a string can't be a number.

What this has to do with your code is that you're trying to convert an **Event** to a **VideoEvent**.

To remedy this, change your code to this line:

```
  comp.addEventListener(VideoEvent.COMPLETE, videoComplete);
```

Comment: thanks that makes sense but when i try the above it says - 1119: Access of possibly undefined property COMPLETE through a reference with static type Class.

Comment: @v1ru2 his answer is correct, but I bet if you look up at your import statements, you will still see flash.event.VideoEvent.  Make sure that ONLY fl.video.VideoEvent is imported. Should solve it!

Comment: thanks, but i dont have "import flash.event.VideoEvent;" all i have was - import fl.video.*; if i add "import flash.event.VideoEvent;" i get this.. 1172: Definition flash.event:VideoEvent could not be found.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a cue point to the end of your video and listen for that.

Assuming comp is the instance name of your flvPlayback component...

```
import fl.video.FLVPlayback;
import fl.video.MetadataEvent;

comp.addEventListener(MetadataEvent.CUE_POINT, video_cp_listener, false, 0, true);

function video_cp_listener(eventObject:MetadataEvent):void {

//run code here when a cue point is found
trace(eventObject.info.name);

}
```